# How to handle data going from a clock domain to another clock domain whose clock is divide by 2 version of the first clock?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have the following code.

```
module tb;

reg clk;
reg clk_2;
reg [15:0] from_flop;
reg [15:0] to_flop;

initial begin
        clk = 0; 
        clk_2 = 0;
        from_flop = 1;
end

always #10 clk = ~clk;


always @(posedge clk) begin
        clk_2 <= ~clk_2;
end


always @(posedge clk) begin
        from_flop <= from_flop + 1; 
end

always @(posedge clk_2) begin
        to_flop <= from_flop; 
end

endmodule
```

However, at time instant 10ns, from_flop and to_flop both get value = 2. This is contrary to what I was expecting. I was expecting from_flop to change from 1 to 2 at 10ns, and to_flop to change from x to 1 at 10ns.

Why is this happening and how to code such that this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually assignments in a sequential block are use non-blocking (`<=`) assignments. The one notable except is for generating derived clocks, which should use blocking (`=`) assignments. Blocking assignments in sequential blocks are legal; but you need to know what you are doing or you will get a functional mismatch between RTL simulation and circuit. That said, you still needed to error on the side of caution when using this approach.

A flip-flop has has a clock to Q delay, there for any derived clocks will have a phase offset from its parent clock. Some synthesizing tools may compensate the offset for you, however you will need to specify all cases where this should happen to the synthesizer; it will not figure it out for you. This means you should not create derived clocks sporadically across the design. All derived clocking signals need to be generated from one dedicated module; this keeps it manageable.

In most cases you should not create any derived clock. Instead, sample every other clock by adding an extra flip-flop.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  from_flop <= from_flop + 1; 
  if (transfer_n==1'b0) begin
    to_flop <= from_flop;
  end
  transfer_n <= ~transfer_n;
end
```

This strategy keeps the design in one clock domain which usually makes synthesis easier with better timing. The area impact from the extra flop in minimal can easily be less then the area penalty from the added buffers needed to keep the derived clocks aligned.

Comment: Hi Greg, do you have any reference for the statement "The one notable except is for generating derived clocks, which should use blocking (=) assignments" ?

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot immediately find any papers to sight. Maybe buried in one of [Cliff Cummings paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/) (I know he has some great papers explaining the challenges and solutions of multi-clock domains), or one of the other resources in listed in my profile. It has to do with the way the verilog scheduler works plus the fact your synthesizer can guarantee it can  keep the edges lined up. Having multiple clocks (both derived and independent) adds complexity and risk. The best option is to keep everything running on the same clock whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
clk_2 <= ~clk_2;
```

You are using a non-blocking assignment, when perhaps you wanted a blocking assignment:

```
clk_2 = ~clk_2;
```

Non-blocking assignments are scheduled after blocking assignments, so the `always @(posedge clk) begin` will always be clocked before `always @(posedge clk_2) begin`.

Obviously, this isn't synthesisable code. So, this is a simulation (scheduling) issue. If you are going to synthesise something with this functionality, consider very carefully how you generate the divided clock.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/AyQ

Comment: The code I posted is a simplification of the actual code. And the code is meant to be synthesized. We use flops to do a divide by 2 right? And the coding guideline is to use non-blocking assignments in sequential blocks right? So, what do you think would be the right way to code a flop which does divide by 2?

Comment: @Rakraks In your model, there is a scheduling delay between clk and clk_2 because non-blocking assignments are always executed after blocking. Real flip-flops have a real delay between the clock input and the Q output: the clock to Q delay. So, if you divide just using a flip-flop and nothing else, your real clk_2 will be really delayed relative to clk and so your real circuit might exhibit the same behaviour. If you're using an FPGA I suggest you read the instructions to find out how to generate derived clocks. If you're designing an IC, you've got a steep learning curve.

Comment: I agree that in reality(Silicon) the clk_2 will be delayed w.r.t clk but the synthesizing tool knows that and will ensure that Q of from_flop is also delayed before coming to D pin of to_flop,so this will work correctly in Silicon and also in gate level simulations. Question is how to code this such that it shows the same behavior in both RTL and gates.

Comment: @Rakraks I'm afraid you're trying to do something I've never done. I've always been very careful with derived clocks and so have never left this kind of thing up to the synthesiser.